# I have to set DOCKER_HOST to localhost in order to deploy to production. Why?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I've been wrestling with remote docker hosts for a few hours now. Each time I try to run

```
$ eval (docker-machine env staging)
$ docker-compose up --build
```

I get this:

```
backports.ssl_match_hostname.CertificateError: hostname 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' doesn't match 'localhost'
```

The first time I got this error, I figured there was something up with my local dns. So I looked at `/etc/hosts` and found that nothing was wrong. I indeed had an entry for ip `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

Then I looked at my docker environment variables. `DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME` was set to my environment and `DOCKER_HOST` was set to `tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2376`. So what could be wrong?

Then I found [this](https://thobalose.co.za/2016/docker-compose-ssl-error/) blog post that suggested changing my `DOCKER_HOST` to localhost. I tried it but it still did not work. Finally, I added an entry to my `etc/hosts` file that bound `localhost` to my remote ip, changed my `DOCKER_HOST` to `localhost` and then tried `docker-compose up`. It worked.

This is simultaneously troubling and relieving. On the one hand, i can deploy to my staging env. But I have to do it using a weird workaround that i dont fully understand. Can anyone explain why this worked? And more importantly, what I was doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is the output of `env | grep DOCKER`:

```
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/home/me/.docker/machine/machines/staging
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:2376
DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=staging
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

and `docker-machine env staging` (i use fish shell):

```
set -gx DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY "1";
set -gx DOCKER_HOST "tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:2376";
set -gx DOCKER_CERT_PATH "/home/me/.docker/machine/machines/staging";
set -gx DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME "staging";
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval (docker-machine env staging)
```

this is on

Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be

docker-machine version 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9

docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown

**UPDATE 2**

I began to think that this was a problem with the ssl certs. So I ran `docker-machine regenerate-certs staging` and redeployed. Still the same issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you amend the question to include the output of `env | grep DOCKER` and `docker-machine env staging` (after sanitizing of course)? It sounds like the `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` might be for your local Docker Machine instead of the remote one. Can you also clarify the version of Docker and docker-machine being used here and also that the Docker Machine hosts in question were actually provisioned by Docker Machine?

Comment: @AndyShinn please see the update. Youre certainly right that my cert path is local, but as long as iv used docker it has been this way. i dont believe the problem stems from there.

Comment: I think this may be a certificate issue. The certificate generated is either using IP or localhost as name and then DOCKER_HOST is not using the same. So if i have a self signed https server deployed using a cert for localhost then `https://127.0.0.1` won't work as the server expects domain name to be localhost

Comment: I ran `docker-machine renerate-certs staging`... so that should have regenerated the certs for the remote host. still no dice.

Comment: This is a reported bug, you will find a workaround here : https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3707